# Zend Framework: What is the difference between no return value and returning the resource instance in a bootstrap init?

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I'm new to this framework.
I've been searching on how to define a custom route and I found this code:

```
protected function _initRouter(){
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();

    $router->addRoute(
            'listOnIndex',     
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/list', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'list'))
        );

return $router;
}
```

I've tried removing the return value and it still works. Why is that?
Is it really necessary to return the instance?
Thank you very much for the help! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you return a value from a boostrap method named `_initSomeResource()`, then the return value is "stored"  in the bootstrap, for possible retrieval later as:

```
$bootstrap->getResource('SomeResource')
```

Since the bootstrap class is passed as an invoke argument to controllers, you are able to access these resources in controllers using:

```
$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
$someResource = $bootstrap->getResource('SomeResource');
```

In your circumstance, the resource you are configuring is the router and you didn't need to access it later on. So in this case, failing to return it from `_initRouter()` didn't hurt you any.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much sir! There are a lot of workarounds in this framework that is needed to be known. Quite different compared to what I'm used to...

Comment: Yeah, it sure feels like a lot to get your head around. I'm better than before, but still learning new stuff all the time. Go, go, go!

Comment: I was earlier saving the database adapter object inside registry for later retrieval... but was no need to... thnks..

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is not neccessary to return the $router instance.

Since you are using a singleton pattern to retrieve the router object and configure a new route via the addRoute method, the added routes are stored savely for further processing (as long as only this instance is used).

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborating it further. Perhaps I'll try to look on those singleton classes present in this framework.